# Query to fetch rows with required data if match is present else NULL, multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `db_make` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` char(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ams`.`db_make`
(`id`,
`title`,
`status`)
VALUES
('1', 'DELL', '1'), ('2', 'SAMSUNG', '1'), ('3', 'APPLE', '1');

CREATE TABLE `db_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` char(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ams`.`db_category`
(`id`,
`title`,
`status`)
VALUES
('1', 'LAPTOP', '1'), ('2', 'MOBILE', '1');

CREATE TABLE `db_model` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` char(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ams`.`db_model`
(`id`,
`title`,
`status`)
VALUES
('1', 'INSPIRON', '1'), ('2', 'IPHONE', '1'), ('3', 'MACBOOK', '1'), ('4', 'NOTEBOOK', '1'), ('5', 'GALAXY', '1');

CREATE TABLE `db_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` text,
  `make` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `db_vendoritem` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vendorid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `make` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ams`.`db_items`
(`id`,
`status`,
`title`,
`make`,
`model`,
`category`,)
VALUES
('1', '1', '5000 Series', '1', '1', '1');

INSERT INTO `ams`.`db_vendoritem`
(`id`,
`vendorid`,
`category`,
`make`,
`model`,
`item`)
VALUES
('1', '1', '1', null, null, null), ('2', '1', '1', '1', null, null), ('3', '1', null, '2', null, null), ('4', '1', null, null, '3', null), ('5', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1');
```

A Vendor may specialize in a model, make, category or item - any one or any combination of them. In the above data vendor with id - 1 specializes in (excuse the data)

```
- all DELL products,  
- all DELL laptops,
- all laptops,
- all Inspiron laptops
```

I need a query that prints - vendorid, make title, category title, model title, item title for all rows in db_vendoritem as shown below:

```
1, DELL,       ,         ,            ;
1, DELL, LAPTOP,         ,            ;
1,     , MOBILE,         ,            ;
1,     ,       ,  MACBOOK,            ;
1, DELL, LAPTOP, INSPIRON, 5000 series;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT VI.`vendorid`
      ,M.`title` `make title`
      ,C.`title` `category title`
      ,MO.`title` `model title`
      ,I.`title` ` item title`
FROM `db_vendoritem` VI
LEFT JOIN `db_items`I ON VI.`item` = I.`id`
LEFT JOIN `db_model`MO ON VI.`model` = MO.`id`
LEFT JOIN `db_category` C ON VI.`category` = C.`id`
LEFT JOIN `db_make` M ON VI.`make` = M.`id`;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d1459869b73244ddf5676abfcf254f7) is he fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code.

```
INSERT INTO `ams`.`db_items`
(`id`,
`status`,
`title`,
`make`,
`model`,
`category`,)
VALUES
('1', '1', '5000 Series', '1', '1', '1');
```

The comma in

```
category,)
```

Not 100% sure if that meets your goal, but this query should give you a start

```
SELECT
 db_vendoritem.`id` AS vendoritem_id, 
 `db_make`.`title` AS make_title,
 `db_model`.`title` AS model_title
FROM 
 `db_vendoritem`
LEFT JOIN
 db_make ON db_make.`id` = db_vendoritem.`make`
LEFT JOIN
  db_model ON db_model.`id` = db_vendoritem.`model`
```